# How to use the quantize function with my json data file

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, visualization, topojson

I have been following the guide for choropleth using D3 from this link.
http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/18/learning-d3-part-7-choropleth-maps

instead of unemployment, I have a json file that lists the number of automobile crashes per county per state. The format of this json file is

```
 {
    "id":1001,
    "crashTotal":2
  },
```

And this is for each of the elements in the json file; one for each county. The ID is the State+County FIPS Code and the crashTotal is its namesake.

I have been following the example code closely and have come upon the quantize function

```
// quantize function takes a data point and returns a number
// between 0 and 8, to indicate intensity, the prepends a 'q'
// and appends '-9'

function quantize(d) {
  return "q" + Math.min(8, ~~(data[d.id] * 9 / 12)) + "-9";
}
```

For me, data is a variable set equal to the crashes.json file. I'm confused as to why I cannot use the crashTotal values from my data to use according to the quantize function.

When I  try to use the following code

```
~~data[d.id] or +data[d.id]
```

I get 0 or NaN. Why is this? I'm fairly new to using d3 so I'm not sure how this is meant to work. Thanks.

My code is quite close to the example code, but with my own US country and state JSON files converted from the census shapefiles. Can someone help?

EDIT: I'd figure I explain the issue a little bit more. Its not a problem between using a quantize function or d3 scale quantize, but rather how to access my data to color each county. As stated, my data file is a JSON in the format above. The following is how I set the data and how I call quantize

```
d3.json("Crashes.json", function(crashes) {

    max = +crashes[0].crashTotal;
    min = +crashes[0].crashTotal;
    maxFIPS = +crashes[0].id;
    minFIPS = +crashes[0].id;
    for(i = 0; i < crashes.length; i++) {
        if(+crashes[i].crashTotal > max) {
            maxFIPS = +crashes[i].id;
            max = +crashes[i].crashTotal;
        }
        if(+crashes[i].crashTotal < min) {
            minFIPS = +crashes[i].id;
            min = +crashes[i].crashTotal;
        }
    }

    data=crashes;

    //for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //  document.writeln(data[i].id + " " + data[i].crashTotal);
//  }

    counties.selectAll("path")
        .attr("class", quantize);
        //.text(function (d){return "" + d.value;});

    //console.log("maxFIPS:" + maxFIPS + " minFIPS:" + minFIPS + "\n" + "max:" + max + " min:" + min);
});

function quantize(d) {

return "q" + Math.min(8, ~~data[d.id]) + "-9";
}
```

If I were to replace data[d.id] in the quantize function above, it would actually color based on the color scheme specified in the  bracket or CSS document. How would I get this to use the CrashTotal numbers from my data?

EDIT[3-6-2014]
     Following the answer from Amelia, I now have the following code bracket.

```
d3.json("Crashes.json", function(crashes) {
        crashDataMap = d3.map();

        crashes.forEach(function(d) {crashDataMap.set(d.id, d);});

        data = crashDataMap.values();
        quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.crashTotal;}))
        .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) {return "q" + i + "-9"}));

        //min = d3.min(crashDataMap.values(), function(d) {return d.crashTotal;});
        //max = d3.max(crashDataMap.values(), function(d) {return d.crashTotal;});
        //console.log(quantize(crashDataMap.get(6037).crashTotal));

        counties.selectAll("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) {return quantize(crashDataMap.get(d.id).crashTotal);});
        });
```

This should get me the correct coloring for my map, but my map stays white. I can confirm that by testing out quantize, I get the correct class name from my CSS file.

```
console.log(quantize(crashDataMap.get(1001).crashTotal)); //returns q0-9
```

More help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT2[3-6-2014] I decided to just post the entire code I have here, hoping someone could make sense out of the madness of why this doesn't work

```
//CSS or <style></style> bracket
svg {
        background: white;
    }

    path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 0.1px;
    }

    #counties path{

        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 0.25px;
    }


    #states path{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 0.5px;
    }

.Blues .q0-9{fill:rgb(247,251,255)}
.Blues .q1-9{fill:rgb(222,235,247)}
.Blues .q2-9{fill:rgb(198,219,239)}
.Blues .q3-9{fill:rgb(158,202,225)}
.Blues .q4-9{fill:rgb(107,174,214)}
.Blues .q5-9{fill:rgb(66,146,198)}
.Blues .q6-9{fill:rgb(33,113,181)}
.Blues .q7-9{fill:rgb(8,81,156)}
.Blues .q8-9{fill:rgb(8,48,107)}

//Crashes.js file
    var width = 960
    var height = 500;

    var data;
    var crashDataMap;
    var quantize;

    var path = d3.geo.path();

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g");


    var counties = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "counties")
        .attr("class", "Blues");

    var states = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "states");


    d3.json("county.json", function(county) {
        var countyFeatures = topojson.feature(county, county.objects.county);
        counties.selectAll("path")
            .data(countyFeatures.features)
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
    }); 

    d3.json("state.json", function(state) {
        var stateFeatures = topojson.feature(state, state.objects.state);
        states.selectAll("path")
            .data(stateFeatures.features)
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path);   

    });


    d3.json("Crashes.json", function(crashes) {
            crashDataMap = d3.map();

            crashes.forEach(function(d) {crashDataMap.set(d.id, d);});

            data = crashDataMap.values();
            quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.crashTotal;}))
            .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) {return "q" + i + "-9"}));

            /*
            for(i  = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(quantize(crashDataMap.get(data[i].id).crashTotal));
            }   
            */

            counties.selectAll("path")
                .attr("class", function(d) {return quantize(crashDataMap.get(d.id).crashTotal);});

        });

            function zoomed() {
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            };
```

Take a look at where I generated the paths for counties. After `.enter().append("path")`
statement, if I were to enter the code `.attr("class", "q8-9)` It would color every county to the scheme defined as q8-9.

If I were to call `counties.selectAll("path").attr("class", "q8-9")` anywhere outside of the code bracket, nothing happens; the map stays white. This is bugging me as I clearly have no idea why this can happen. I can verify that the path elements are there for both county and state.

Comment: Can you output the contents of 'data' after your preperations and put it here?

Comment: I have to iterate through data like so ==>>

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
     document.writeln(data[i].id + " " data[i].crashTotal);

Seeing that data has about 3000 elements. I'll post it all on pastebin through the following link

http://pastebin.com/SH74Hhnn

Comment: I just noticed there is a null value in my printout. My data is missing a number for crashTotal. I'll fix it now, but I'm still stuck on the above issue.

Comment: Instead of using a quantize function, you can use D3's quantize scales -- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

Comment: I've also been using that as a source. My question is how to determine the domain and range for using d3 quantize scales. The domain I think would be the [min, max] of the crashTotals from my data while the range would somehow return the class name of one of the defined colors within the <style></style> bracket. Would this also be possible without queues because the example use queues? Regardless, the problem still stands that I do not know how to access the crashTotal value from my data using this particular quantize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To explain what's going on in the original code:**

The tutorial you linked to uses *two* data files, one for the maps and one for the data values.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to include links to the actual data files used, but their both JSON.  The counties have an 'id' property and that property seems to be used as the keys in the second JSON data file.  I.e., that second file (`data`) must be of the form:

```
{
  "1001":   ".097",
  "1003":   ".091",
  "1005":   ".134",
  /*...*/
}
```

This is different from the data structure used in the [very similar Mike Bostock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606), which uses a .tsv file for the unemployment data, which is then used to generate a [`d3.map`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_map) hashmap data dictionary.

```
var rateById = d3.map();
queue.defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
//this is equivalent to 
/*
  d3.tsv("unemployment.tsv", 
         function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); }, 
        readyFunction );
*/
//except that the readyFunction is only run when *both* data files are loaded.

//When two functions are given as parameters to d3.tsv, 
//the first one is called on each row of the data.
//In this case, it adds the id and rate as a key:value pair to the hashmap
```

Both of these examples end up with a data structure where the id values are keys that can be used to grab the appropriate data value.  In contrast, your data are in an unkeyed array, with your id values as just another property, not as a key.  That is why `data[d.id]` was returning an error for you -- instead of grabbing a data number that matches that id, it's grabbing an element of your array at the index equivalent the id number.  That either returns an object, which becomes `NaN` when converted to a number, or undefined, which becomes zero.

In either example, once they have the number, they then want to convert it to an integer from 0 to 8 in order to assign one of the [ColorBrewer](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer) class names to the path.  The Scott Becker tutorial uses a somewhat arbitrary calculation for this, the Mike Bostock example uses a quantize scale with a hard-coded domain.  You say you want to figure out a domain based on your data.

**To help you figure out what you need to do:**

Your first step is to get your crash data into a structure where you can easily grab a data element based on its id value.

One option would be to create a `d3.map` object (`var crashDataMap = d3.map();`) and then use a `forEach` call on your existing data array to add each object to the map using [`map.set(key, value)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-map_set) with its id as the key.

```
crashDataArray.forEach( function(d){ crashDataMap.set( d.id, d) });
```

Then when you are setting the class on your shapes, you can use `crashDataMap.get(d.id)` to grab the crash data that matches the shape's id, and you can extract the correct number from that.

For dividing your data into categories, you probably want to use a quantize scale similar to Mike Bostock's example.  On your original data array, you can use [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) with an appropriate accessor function to grab the crash totals from each entry and find the max and min for setting the domain.

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a shot and see how it works. 
I already have the max and min from the above loop so I think I can keep that instead for the domain.

Comment: I have edit the problem with my current situation. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Can you check in the DOM whether the paths are being given the correct class names?  As far as I can tell from your updated code they should be.  Which suggests to me that the problem is with your CSS.  Are you using CSS rules like `.Blues .q0-9{fill:rgb(247,251,255)}`, like in the example?  Because then you would need to add the class "Blues" to your svg as a whole.

Comment: If your paths *aren't* getting the classes added, then the problem is probably that this code is running before your paths are actually created -- i.e., before the callback function from your geoJSON file is finished.

Comment: Yes I do. counties = svg.append("g").attr("id", "counties").attr("class", "Blues");

Comment: This crashes.json code bracket comes after the call to d3.json("URL for counties.json" function(counties)) bracket. So if what you are saying that the paths are done generating after this finishes running, would this be the reason?

Comment: It seems that if I try to select all path elements outside of the generation code of county.json, nothing is applied. As in for example:     counties.selectAll("path").attr("class", "q8-9");      doesn't work anywhere.

I can clearly see the path elements of the county.json within the DOM however

Comment: I'm truly sorry that all my problems are there, but can you please take a look at my newest edit?

Comment: This is gonna be off the top here, but does this issue have something to do with Apatana? I'm using that to develop this visualization.

Comment: The problem is the asynchronous nature of the code -- the code inside the `d3.json` callback functions runs whenever that particular file is ready, not in the order they are written in your program.  The Mike Bostock example got around this by using `d3.queue` to only run one callback after all the files had been read.  The Scott Becker tutorial got around it by having code at the end of *both* callback functions for adding the data classes to the county paths, depending on whether the paths and/or data existed.  Check that tutorial again for how he did it.

Comment: I've been thinking that as well, so I tried to use queue, however, I have another problem with that, which I located into another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247330/d3-topojson-and-queue-error