# Queue error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of null"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapping, topojson, queue.js

I'm trying to using queues to ensure my files are loaded fully before the script continues. However, when I load in my json map files and try to use them in a function, I get an error.

```
var counties = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "counties")
    .attr("class", "Blues");

var states = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");

    queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "county.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "state.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "Crashes.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(county, state, crashes) {
    var countyFeatures = topojson.feature(county, county.objects.counties);
    var stateFeatures = topojson.feature(state, state.objects.states);

    /*
    counties.selectAll("path")
        .data(county.features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "q8-9")
        .attr("d", path);

    states.selectAll("path")
        .data(state.features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);   
      */
}
```

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of null`

Can someone explain why when passing into the function it is null? As opposed to running d3.json separately and using

```
d3.json("URL", function(d) {var temp = topojson.feature(d, d.objects.counties;});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first parameter of your `ready` function should always be "error".  So the fact that it is `null` is actually a good thing!  Rewrite it as `function ready(error, county, state, crashes) {` etc., and all should be well.

Comment: Thanks! However, I still have the problem with my json files. Truly sorry about this. I posted it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245367/d3-help-us-counties-json-file-only-displays-half-of-the-counties